# Anychart Feature Zoom error

Tags: anychart

I was using Anychart 6 on Oracle Apex 4.1. After migration to Apex 5.1, I have problem with Anychart. It's completely not working, I see "Error message: feature is not supported. Feature: Zoom".

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: when exactly do you get this error? are you talking about the maps?

Comment: No. I see this error, from the beginning of page loading, in area where simple linear chart should be presented.

Comment: could you please contact us via support@anychart.com and provide the full code from "Source" and "Chart options" text areas?